# Animate image like it's moving from right to left

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations

I am trying to animate a floor which should move from right to left like the clouds and it work but the problem is it overflows outside the container. How can I prevent this to happen? Sorry I am new to css animation. Thanks in advance.

Here is the fiddle I made: Click [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ft53344u/)

```css
.container {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}

#clouds{
    padding: 100px 0;
    background: #3598dc;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3598dc 0%, #fff 100%);
    background: -linear-gradient(top, #3598dc 0%, #fff 100%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3598dc 0%, #fff 100%);
}

.cloud {
    width: 200px; height: 60px;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 200px;
    -moz-border-radius: 200px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 200px;
    position: relative;
}

.cloud:before, .cloud:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    background: #fff;
    width: 100px; height: 80px;
    position: absolute; top: -15px; left: 10px;

    border-radius: 100px;
    -moz-border-radius: 100px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg);
    transform: rotate(30deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(30deg);
}

.cloud:after {
    width: 120px; height: 120px;
    top: -55px; left: auto; right: 15px;
}

#character{
    margin-top: -120px;
    background:url(http://i.imgur.com/Zjsbcni.png);
    width: 84px;
    height: 126px;
    animation: walk 1.0s steps(6) infinite;
    margin-left: 425px;
}

#flooring {
    height: 39px;
    background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/usFekrp.png);
    animation: movefloor 20s linear infinite;
    overflow: hidden;
}

@keyframes movefloor {
    0% {margin-left: 1000px;}
    100% {margin-left: -1000px;}
}

@keyframes walk {
    from { background-position: 0px; }
    to { background-position: -500px; }
}

.x1 {
    -webkit-animation: moveclouds 15s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: moveclouds 15s linear infinite;
    -o-animation: moveclouds 15s linear infinite;
}

.x2 {
    left: 200px;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.6);
    -moz-transform: scale(0.6);
    transform: scale(0.6);
    opacity: 0.6; /*opacity proportional to the size*/

    -webkit-animation: moveclouds 25s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: moveclouds 25s linear infinite;
    -o-animation: moveclouds 25s linear infinite;
}

.x3 {
    left: 252px;
    top: -200px;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.8);
    -moz-transform: scale(0.8);
    transform: scale(0.8);
    opacity: 0.8; /*opacity proportional to the size*/

    -webkit-animation: moveclouds 20s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: moveclouds 20s linear infinite;
    -o-animation: moveclouds 20s linear infinite;
}


@-webkit-keyframes moveclouds {
    0% {margin-left: 1000px;}
    100% {margin-left: -1000px;}
}
@-moz-keyframes moveclouds {
    0% {margin-left: 1000px;}
    100% {margin-left: -1000px;}
}
@-o-keyframes moveclouds {
    0% {margin-left: 1000px;}
    100% {margin-left: -1000px;}
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div id="clouds">
        <div class="cloud x1"></div>
        <div class="cloud x2"></div>
        <div class="cloud x3"></div>
        <div class="cloud x4"></div>
        <div class="cloud x5"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="character"></div>
    <div id="flooring"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: `overflow: hidden`?

Comment: Please check the working fiddle for reference

Comment: Add `overflow: hidden` to the div `#clouds`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add `overflow: hidden;` to id "clouds"

```
   #clouds{
      overflow: hidden;
    }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/p7noxpx1/1/

example with flooring https://jsfiddle.net/ggb62cux/4/

Comment: Yea it fixes the clouds but I wonder why the flooring doesn't work.

Comment: Hey! thanks this is what I am looking for. Can you explain how you do the flooring?

Answer (score 2):

Add a `overflow:hidden` to `#clouds`:

```css
body {
    font-family: 'Candal', sans-serif;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color:black;

    /* remove this line, this is to prove the cloud is invisible ^^^ */
}

.container {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}

#clouds{
    padding: 100px 0;
    background: #3598dc;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3598dc 0%, #fff 100%);
    background: -linear-gradient(top, #3598dc 0%, #fff 100%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3598dc 0%, #fff 100%);
    overflow:hidden;

    /* add this line ^^^ */
}

.cloud {
    width: 200px; height: 60px;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 200px;
    -moz-border-radius: 200px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 200px;

    position: relative;
}

.cloud:before, .cloud:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    background: #fff;
    width: 100px; height: 80px;
    position: absolute; top: -15px; left: 10px;

    border-radius: 100px;
    -moz-border-radius: 100px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 100px;

    -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg);
    transform: rotate(30deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(30deg);
}

.cloud:after {
    width: 120px; height: 120px;
    top: -55px; left: auto; right: 15px;
}

#character{
    margin-top: -120px;
    background:url(http://i.imgur.com/Zjsbcni.png);
    width: 84px;
    height: 126px;
    animation: walk 1.0s steps(6) infinite;
    margin-left: 425px;
}

#flooring {
    height: 39px;
    background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/usFekrp.png);
    animation: movefloor 20s linear infinite;
    overflow: hidden;
}

@keyframes movefloor {
    0% {margin-left: 1000px;}
    100% {margin-left: -1000px;}
}

@keyframes walk {
    from { background-position: 0px; }
    to { background-position: -500px; }
}

.x1 {
    -webkit-animation: moveclouds 15s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: moveclouds 15s linear infinite;
    -o-animation: moveclouds 15s linear infinite;
}

/*variable speed, opacity, and position of clouds for realistic effect*/
.x2 {
    left: 200px;

    -webkit-transform: scale(0.6);
    -moz-transform: scale(0.6);
    transform: scale(0.6);
    opacity: 0.6; /*opacity proportional to the size*/

    /*Speed will also be proportional to the size and opacity*/
    /*More the speed. Less the time in 's' = seconds*/
    -webkit-animation: moveclouds 25s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: moveclouds 25s linear infinite;
    -o-animation: moveclouds 25s linear infinite;
}

.x3 {
    left: 252px;
    top: -200px;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.8);
    -moz-transform: scale(0.8);
    transform: scale(0.8);
    opacity: 0.8; /*opacity proportional to the size*/

    -webkit-animation: moveclouds 20s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: moveclouds 20s linear infinite;
    -o-animation: moveclouds 20s linear infinite;
}

.x4 {
    left: 470px;
    top: -250px;

    -webkit-transform: scale(0.75);
    -moz-transform: scale(0.75);
    transform: scale(0.75);
    opacity: 0.75; /*opacity proportional to the size*/

    -webkit-animation: moveclouds 18s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: moveclouds 18s linear infinite;
    -o-animation: moveclouds 18s linear infinite;
}

.x5 {
    left: -150px;
    top: -150px;

    -webkit-transform: scale(0.8);
    -moz-transform: scale(0.8);
    transform: scale(0.8);
    opacity: 0.8; /*opacity proportional to the size*/

    -webkit-animation: moveclouds 20s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: moveclouds 20s linear infinite;
    -o-animation: moveclouds 20s linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes moveclouds {
    0% {margin-left: 1000px;}
    100% {margin-left: -1000px;}
}
@-moz-keyframes moveclouds {
    0% {margin-left: 1000px;}
    100% {margin-left: -1000px;}
}
@-o-keyframes moveclouds {
    0% {margin-left: 1000px;}
    100% {margin-left: -1000px;}
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>CSS3 Animation</h1>
  <div id="clouds">
  <div class="cloud x1"></div>
  <div class="cloud x2"></div>
  <div class="cloud x3"></div>
  <div class="cloud x4"></div>
  <div class="cloud x5"></div>
 </div>
  <div id="character"></div>
  <div id="flooring"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yea it fixes the clouds but I wonder why the flooring doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Pugazh/ft53344u/2/)

**Fix 1: Clouds overflowing the container:**

`overflow: hidden` on the body will only hide the elements overflowing the body of page.So you would need to add `overflow: hidden` to the div `#clouds`.

Modify `#clouds` as below:

```
#clouds {
  padding: 100px 0;
  background: #3598dc;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3598dc 0%, #fff 100%);
  background: -linear-gradient(top, #3598dc 0%, #fff 100%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3598dc 0%, #fff 100%);
overflow: hidden;
}
```

**Fix 2: Floor animation is hidden**
Floor animation is hidden because it's overflowing the body. Change `overlfow: hidden` in body to `overflow-x: hidden`

Modify `body` as below:

```
body {
  font-family: 'Candal', sans-serif;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Yea it fixes the clouds but I wonder why the flooring doesn't work.

Comment: It's hidden because it's overflowing the body. Change `overlfow: hidden` in body to `overflow-x: hidden`. [Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Pugazh/ft53344u/4/)

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**

I think you should add an `overflow: hidden;` to `.container` and `#clouds` because every element is contained in `.container`. The clouds are positioned absolute, so they may overflow inside `.container` thus `overflow: hidden;` is applied on `#clouds`. Also change the margin of the `#character` if you want it to be inside the container.

**CSS**

```
 .container {           
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  width: 50%;
}

#clouds {           
  background: #3598dc;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3598dc 0%, #fff 100%);
  background: -linear-gradient(top, #3598dc 0%, #fff 100%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3598dc 0%, #fff 100%);
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 100px 0;      
}

#character{
  animation: walk 1.0s steps(6) infinite;
  background:url(http://i.imgur.com/Zjsbcni.png);      
  height: 126px;  
  margin-left: 320px;
  margin-top: -120px;
  width: 84px;
}
```

[Check this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ft53344u/3/)